# Date diff between many rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have USER_ID, EVENT_ID and DATE and I need to check which of the events are real.

Real event is the first one by each user and every one which is at least 10 days after the last real event.

What i do is to order them by USER_ID and date and using this forumla `=IF(A2<>A1;1;IF(C2-C1>=10;1;0))` but that way it calculates date diff between current and the previous event, not to the last real event.

Like if i have events at 01 05 and 13 from one user it will give me 1, 0, 0 but i need to compare to the last real event which is at 01 and it should give me 1, 0 ,1.

How can i do that.

```
| USER ID  | EVENT ID  |    DATE      |  What I get   | What I should get |    
|:---------|:---------:|:------------:| :------------:|:------------:     |
| 1        |        4  |  01.01.2020  |       1       |       1           |
| 1        |        5  |  05.01.2020  |       0       |       0           |
| 1        |        6  |  13.01.2020  |       0       |       1           |
| 2        |        7  |  03.01.2020  |       1       |       1           |
| 2        |        8  |  05.01.2020  |       0       |       0           |
| 2        |        9  |  06.01.2020  |       0       |       0           |
```

The number of events by user is not fixed.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oaaN.png)
[image]

Comment: please [edit] the post to include some test data in tabular form with expected output.

Comment: Tried to make it to look like table but it just don't work. Added screen shot if that is ok ?

Comment: now you can (if you want) remove the screen shot ....

Comment: This doesn't match your output: `=IF(A1<>A2,1,0)` - if you start it from D1 you get 0,0,1,0,0,1, and if you start it from D2 you get "",0,0,1,0,0.

Comment: A1 is user_id A2 is 1 and it's <> A1, I don't know if it's correct to use it that way but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in VBA.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
'data
Cells.Clear
[a2:b7] = [{1,1;1,5;1,13;2,3;2,5;2,6}]
'code
lre = [b2]
For i = 2 To 7
  If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
    Cells(i, 3) = 1
  ElseIf Cells(i, 2) - lre >= 10 Then
    Cells(i, 3) = 1
    lre = Cells(i, 2)
  Else
    Cells(i, 3) = 0
  End If
Next i
End Sub
```

It uses the same logic as your formula, but uses the `lre` variable to store the last real event's date.

[image: output]

Comment: If the dates are `01-01, 13-01, 25-01` this wil fail, because 13-01 will also be a 'real'-event?

Comment: IF(A2<>A1;1;IF(C2-$C$1>=10;1;0)) This will make it to compare to first event, I need it to be compared to last real event.

Comment: @Luuk; it won't fail there because 25-01>=10 anyway.

Comment: I think this will do great job tho I prefer to not enter manually the array couse there are 700 000 rows