# Excel loop for corresponding cells

Tags: excel, vba

How can i make a loop working only for corresponding cells. Like i need this to work for 700000 rows without prefixing it manually.

```vba
Sub Button1_Click()
'data

    Cells.Clear
    [a2:b7] = [{1,1;1,5;1,13;2,3;2,5;2,6}]
    'code
    lre = [b2]
    For i = 2 To 7
      If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        Cells(i, 3) = 1
      ElseIf Cells(i, 2) - lre >= 10 Then
        Cells(i, 3) = 1
        lre = Cells(i, 2)
      Else
        Cells(i, 3) = 0
      End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

```
| USER ID  | EVENT ID  |    DATE      |  What I get   | What I should get |    
|:---------|:---------:|:------------:| :------------:|:------------:     |
| 1        |        4  |  01.01.2020  |       1       |       1           |
| 1        |        5  |  05.01.2020  |       0       |       0           |
| 1        |        6  |  13.01.2020  |       0       |       1           |
| 2        |        7  |  03.01.2020  |       1       |       1           |
| 2        |        8  |  05.01.2020  |       0       |       0           |
| 2        |        9  |  06.01.2020  |       0       |       0           |
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 3) = 1` overwrites the Date column data in Row i with 1. Shouldn't it be `Cells(i, 4) = 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
Sub markCells()
Dim oCell As Range
Dim sCurrentUser As String
Dim dLastEvent As Date
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    ActiveSheet.Columns(4).ClearContents
    Set oCell = [A2]
    sCurrentUser = vbNullString
    dLastEvent = 0
    While oCell.Text <> vbNullString
        If sCurrentUser <> oCell.Text Then
            sCurrentUser = oCell.Text
            oCell.Offset(0, 3) = 1
            dLastEvent = oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value2
        Else
            If oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value2 - dLastEvent > 9 Then ' same >= 10
                oCell.Offset(0, 3) = 1
                dLastEvent = oCell.Offset(0, 2).Value2
            End If
        End If
        Set oCell = oCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub
```

700,000 lines will be processed in a minute or two. However, if you can wait a week for the final revision of [the existing working code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841530/14094617), then two minutes will not be a problem for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, i get some error - "expected function or variable", compiler marks ".Calculate =" at 7th row. Any idea why ?.

Comment: Of course, it just typo: write Calculation instead Calculate